# Unexpected behavior of .I in dt[.I,]

Tags: r, data.table

From `data.table` help, I considered `.I` to be more or less equivalent to `seq_len(nrow(dt))`. But seems it doesn't work the same when placed in `[i,` context of data.table. In the following example I am trying to flag (modify value of a column) all rows after 10th:

```
data(iris)
setDT(iris)
iris[               .I   > 10L, newCol:='10+!'] # doesn't work
iris[seq_len(nrow(iris)) > 10L, newCol:='10+!'] # this works
```

Why `.I` doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben373 provides a nice snippet from the documentation, and a working solution. In addition, in this case one could also do:

```
iris[, newCol:=fifelse(.I>10, '10+!', as.character(NA))]
```

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

> .SD, .BY, .N, .I, .GRP, and .NGRP are read-only symbols for use in j. .N can be used in i as well. .I can be used in by as well. See the vignettes, Details and Examples here and in data.table. .EACHI is a symbol passed to by; i.e. by=.EACHI.

You could achieve the desired behavior by chaining

```
data(iris)
setDT(iris)
iris[, .i := .I][.i> 10L, newCol:='10+!'][,.i := NULL]
```

Be aware to not name a variable `.I` in a `data.table` because then trying to drop it will result in an error, hence, `iris[, .I := .I][, .I := NULL]` won't work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! In my use case the solution with `fifelse()` fits better though yours is more universal